# Swift simulator won't launch in Xcode, despite successful build

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I have a copy of Xcode 7.3 on my Mac and have been using it recently to develop in Swift. When I would run my code in the past, I noticed the app simulator would take a long time to boot up, and would often be unresponsive or have several errors for a period of time before starting to work as necessary in running my app.

Today, however, I went to run my code again, and the simulator fails to launch or run altogether. When I ran my code it said "build successful" but it has been almost 10 minutes and the simulator has not yet even popped up. Furthermore when I go to press the "stop" button to halt the application it doesn't seem to register this either.

Does anyone know what is wrong? I've been searching for the answer on here and Google for hours and have yet to find a way to fix this. Should I perhaps download the beta version of Xcode 8?

Comment: Clean DerivedData (`m -frd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`). Reset simulators.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the problem still persists

Comment: I had lots of issues with 7.3 -- try 7.3.1.

Comment: It actually is 7.3.1- my apologies, made a mistake in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Preston: don't upgrade to Beta if the latest stable version is giving you issues. It might be good to uninstall and then reinstall your current version. Perhaps that might work. Follow this guide for help uninstalling (contains info for recent versions): http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/

This may seem like an obvious question but have you renamed any of your project files recently? When you go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme, under Run, is the correct  "Your-Project.app" selected for Executable? Make sure you do a quick Clean "shift-command-k" after changing file names or schemes.

Also, try Simulator > Reset Content and Settings. Some people report that as helping fix freezing/non-responsive problems.

Comment: I double checked and the executable name matches the name of my project, but I will keep that in mind when I change file names in the future. I think I will try uninstalling and re-installing and see what happens

Comment: uninstalling won't delete the current Xcode project files I have saved on my computer, correct? Just want to make sure

Comment: After you see "Build Successful" pop up, what happens in the activity window at the top of xcode? Does it say "Running <your-app> on <device>"? Or "<your-app> | Build <your-app>: Succeeded | Today at <time>" That will determine if the problem is actually the simulator or if it is xcode.

Comment: it says "Running <my-app> on <device>"

Comment: Try Simulator > Reset Content and Settings

Comment: where do I find "Simulator"?

Comment: It's for the simulator app. Go into the app, and in its menu select Reset Content and Settings

Comment: The app won't even open if I directly click on it, and no window for it will currently open. Is there another way for me to access its menu?

Comment: Close down both xcode and simulator (force close if necessary). Restart your mac just to be sure all relevant processes are closed down. Then try opening simulator on its own. Command-Space to open spotlight and type simulator. See if it will open up then.

Any chance you are using BetterTouchTool? People claim simulator freezes with that.

Comment: I restarted my computer and clicked Reset Content and Settings for the simulator and it worked this time! I'm not sure if it had to do with memory, restarting the computer, or something else. To answer your question, I am not using BetterTouchTool (or any other 3rd party tool for that matter). Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't download the Xcode 8 if you are having problems in Xcode 7. Normally the beta versions cause more problems. The simulator takes up a lot of memory and if you're machine has less than 8 gb of RAM it could be the reason it is running so slow.

Comment: by 8gb of ram do you mean Xcode needs the full 8gb to run, or my machine should have 8gb total? In the past I upgraded my RAM so that my machine has a total RAM of 8gb, but when I ran Xcode only about 4-5gb of RAM are free for the program naturally due to other things running on my computer. With that being said I tried to clear up as much memory as I could, and the problem persists. Do you have any other insights as to what I can try?

Comment: My machine only has about 4-5 gb available and the simulator runs fine so it must not be that. Did you try doing what Lou Franco said in the comments and reset the simulators??

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify no Xcode will not delete your projects if you uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind for sure. The problem is resolved now without the need for uninstallation, so that is good. I appreciate your help